# Restore Database from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2005

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have created a set of tables (around 20) in SQL Server 2008 and entered around 1000 records to appropriate tables.

But the issue is that I want that same tables with all the entered data into SQL Server 2005 (SQLEXPRESS).

Obviously it won't work by taking a backup and restore it into SQL Server 2005 as it won't support backward compatibility.

Any suggestion would be appreciated....

Comment: And next time you will not develop on a newer database than the one you are using in pord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got Management Studio (including Express version) then you can export data from it (and target an SQL Server version). Try this:

1. Right-click the database you wish to export and select `Tasks > Generate Scripts`
2. Follow the wizard prompts and tick 'Export all objects'
3. In the 'Script Options' dialogue look through all the options and change `'Script for Server Version'` to `'SQL Server 2005'` and also change `'Script Data'` option to `'True'` (this exports the DB content as well as the schema).

You can then save the export as an SQL script in a text-file that can then be run against the database you wish to import it into.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for your reply... But how it can handle the auto generated ID fields in each table ? And how it will resolve the foreign keys ?

Comment: Consider that `Generate SQL Server Scripts Wizard` is crappy f** sh**!! It's seems that it has no changes since SQL 2000 and doesn't work in most of cases returning different errors like `The specified network name is no longer available`

Comment: I think its just generating the script for table structure.. But what if I want all the inserted records also into my MSSql 2005? Thanks..

Comment: @Nimal: Like I said, in the Options you need to select 'Script Data' to 'True'. @abatishchev: I've used the SQL Server scripts export wizard for many databases, including so very complex ones, and it has always worked flawlessly.

Comment: @Dan Diplo: You're lucky! I tried to use it several times for different databases - and every time it fails. I don't know why..